# How do I change the style used by the "Archive" view to show the dates?

Tags: views

By default the "Archive" `views` module displays the dates as "May 2011." I want to change them to "2011 year May."

How do I do that? Is it possible?

`from the instructions of googletorp`: i made the following but it's not work. what's wrong with my code?

1. created a module named `customviews`. which have files(`customviews.info`, `customviews.module`, `customviews.views.inc`)
2. `customviews.module` has code:

   ```
       <?php
         function customviews_views_api(){
           return array('api'=>2);
         }
   ```

   function customviews_views_data_alter(&$data) {
                // Set the argument to the handler you named above.
                $data['node']['created_year_month']['argument']['handler'] = 'custom_handler';
              }
3. `customviews.views.inc` has code

   ```
    <?php
      class custom_handler extends views_handler_argument_node_created_year_month {
        function construct() {
          parent::construct();
          $this->format = "Y year M month"; 
        }
      }
   ```

i have cleared the cache.

i put the **function customviews_views_data_alter(&$data)** into the .module file. it's still can't work. what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Views haven't supplied an easy way of doing this, but it is possible. To do this you would have to create your own handler and make views use that:

#### 1. Creating own handler

```
class custom_handler extends views_handler_argument_node_created_year_month {
  function construct() {
    parent::construct();
    $this->format = 'F Y'; // Write your custom format here.
  }
}
```

#### 2. Making view use your custom format

```
function module_name_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  // Set the argument to the handler you named above.
  $data['node']['created_year_month']['argument']['handler'] = 'custom_handler';
}
```

Update.

1. The custom_handler class or whatever you choose to call it need to go in it's own file. For Drupal 7 the standard is to put it in a dir called handlers which is located in the dir that you specify with `hook_views_api`, and add the file as include in the .info file (Look at the views module for reference).
2. For the module_name_views_data_alter you need to replace module_name, with the name of your module.
3. Clear cache.

Comment: i am sorry, i put your code into my customed module. the data format wasn't  changed. thank you. i researched this question a whole day.. i am new of object programme. could you give some explaination to your code? many thanks

Comment: i only changed your code $this->format = 'F Y'; to $this->format = 'F year Y month ';

Comment: it shows broken/missing handler on the views archive block setting page

Comment: i am sorry,i do it again. it invoke all the article title and content at the archive block part,i put the ways which i did on my questions. what's wrong with it?

Comment: i am sorry, i am not able to edit the code. the format is bad in the question

Comment: @enjoy you need to put the customviews_views_data_alter function in the .module file, since it's a hook.

Comment: i am sorry. i put the code into the .module file,it still can't work. the contextual filter shows"broked /missing handler." could you do test to the code? thank you.